# how to pass php var to a function that defined in a js file

Tags: php, javascript, function, parameters

It works well if I pass no param to the function myFunction, but if I pass a param like '$word', it does not work.

No param:
php file:

```
<?php
......
$word="bulabula";
$hint="<li onclick='myFunction()'>" . $word . "</li>";
......
echo $hint;
?>
```

html file:
......

```
<script>
  function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("s_form_q").value="bulabula";
}
</script>
```

With param:
php file:

```
<?php
......
$word="bulabula";
$hint="<li onclick='myFunction($word)'>" . $word . "</li>";
......
echo $hint;
?>
```

html file:
......

```
<script>
function myFunction(str){
        document.getElementById("s_form_q").value=str;
}
```

Comment: I warmly suggest to avoid mixing server side scripts and the client side scripts. Let the client make a call to a server .php page instead and let the client business process the returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the param you are passing:

With:

```
$hint="<li onclick='myFunction($word)'>" . $word . "</li>";
```

And suppose `$word` is `"hello"`, the above line will output:

```
<li onclick='myFunction(hello)'>hello</li>
```

instead of

```
<li onclick='myFunction("hello")'>hello</li>
```

The correct usage is:

```
$hint="<li onclick='myFunction(\"$word\")'>" . $word . "</li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$hint="<li onclick='myFunction($word)'>" . $word . "</li>";`

to

`$hint="<li onclick='myFunction(\"$word\")'>" . $word . "</li>";`

`\` will escape your parameter, and `$word` will be replace with its content